# C# : Passing a Generic Object

Tags: c#, generics, methods

I want to have a generic print function...PrintGeneric(T)...in the following case, what am I missing?

As always your help/insight is appreciated...

```
public interface ITest
{}

public class MyClass1 : ITest
{
    public string myvar = "hello 1";
}

public class MyClass2 : ITest
{
    public string myvar = "hello 2";
}

class DoSomethingClass
{

    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass1 test1 = new MyClass1();
        MyClass2 test2 = new MyClass2();

        Console.WriteLine(test1.myvar);
        Console.WriteLine(test2.myvar);             
        Console.WriteLine(test1.GetType());

        PrintGeneric(test1);
        PrintGeneric<test2.GetType()>(test2);
    }

    // following doesn't compile
    public void PrintGeneric<T>(T test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic : " + test.myvar);
    }
}
```

Comment: `var` cannot be a variable name as it is a keyword. Can you show your actual code.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Not correct. `var` is a contextual keyword added in C# 3.0. You can use it as an identifier name. Similarly, you can use `yield`, `select`, `from`, etc. as identifier names in most contexts.

Comment: actually "var" did work without using just Console.WriteLine...but that was my bad to use a keyword as a identifier name...

Comment: In this case we managed to guess successfully where your problem lied and what the error was. However, you shouldn't rely on our psychic powers too much ;-) In general, it makes everyone's life easier if you precisely indicate the code line where the error occurs, and post the exact error message too.

Comment: haha sorry I'll try to do so in the future. thx!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It doesn't compile because T could be anything, and not everything will have the `myvar` field.

You could make `myvar` a property on `ITest`:

```
public ITest
{
    string myvar{get;}
}
```

and implement it on the classes as a property:

```
public class MyClass1 : ITest
{
    public string myvar{ get { return "hello 1"; } }
}
```

and then put a generic constraint on your method:

```
public void PrintGeneric<T>(T test) where T : ITest
{
    Console.WriteLine("Generic : " + test.myvar);
}
```

but in that case to be honest you are better off just passing in an ITest:

```
public void PrintGeneric(ITest test)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Generic : " + test.myvar);
}
```

Comment: I added a property to ITest, but then it tells me I need to implement it in MyClass1/MyClass2...which makes sense, but then I get an error saying it already contains a definition for myvar

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to then change the fields to be properties in the implementing classes. Updated my answer to show you.

Comment: i tried PrintGeneric<test2.GetType()>(test2) in Main for the generic and get an 'Only assignment, call, increment, decrement used as a statement'

and PrintGeneric(test1) for PrintGeneric(ITest test)..and get a "An object reference is required for non-static field"

Comment: ok, i see I see I need to change to 'public static void PrintGeneric(ITest test)'...still unsure why PrintGeneric<T> says only assignment/call/increment can be used as a statement

Answer (score 8):

You're missing at least a couple of things:

- Unless you're using reflection, the type arguments need to be known at compile-time, so you can't use

  ```
  PrintGeneric<test2.GetType()>
  ```

  ... although in this case you don't need to anyway
- `PrintGeneric` doesn't know anything about `T` at the moment, so the compiler can't find a member called `T`

Options:

- Put a property in the `ITest` interface, and change `PrintGeneric` to constrain `T`:

  ```
  public void PrintGeneric<T>(T test) where T : ITest
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Generic : " + test.PropertyFromInterface);
  }
  ```
- Put a property in the `ITest` interface and remove the generics entirely:

  ```
  public void PrintGeneric(ITest test)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Property : " + test.PropertyFromInterface);
  }
  ```
- Use dynamic typing instead of generics if you're using C# 4

Comment: Typo in your second code snippet there Jon? You said remove generics but there's still a <T> on the method?

Comment: @SteveHaigh: Doh, that's what I get for typing and talking on the phone at the same time. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: trying the first option...I add "string myvar {get;}" to ITest...
but get an error saying MyClass1/MyClass2 don't implement Interface member 'ITest.myvar'...adding "string myvar {get;}" to MyClass1/MyClass2 results in compile error saying its already defined?

Comment: @user1229895: You can't declare a concrete property like that... but that has nothing to do with generics. You can use an automatically implemented property to implement it in MyClass1 with `public string myvar { get; private set; }`. If that's not enough help, I suggest you ask a separate question.

Comment: As far as I know dynamic types are not recommended for basic functionalities like this. It should be your last resort.

Comment: @Ozkan: Well it is last in the list here... although I'd say that using dynamic typing instead of manually-written reflection can be useful to effectively offload the reflection code to a well-tested codebase.

Answer (score 2):

In your generic method, `T` is just a placeholder for a type. However, the compiler doesn't per se know anything about the concrete type(s) being used runtime, so it can't assume that they will have a `var` member.

The usual way to circumvent this is to add a generic type constraint to your method declaration to ensure that the types used implement a specific interface (in your case, it could be `ITest`):

```
public void PrintGeneric<T>(T test) where T : ITest
```

Then, the members of that interface would be directly available inside the method. However, your `ITest` is currently empty, you need to declare common stuff there in order to enable its usage within the method.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to provide more information about the generic type `T`. In your current `PrintGeneric` method, `T` might as well be a `string`, which does not have a `var` member.

You may want to change `var` to a property rather than a field

```
public interface ITest
{
    string var { get; }
}
```

And add a constraint `where T: ITest` to the `PrintGeneric` method.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public void PrintGeneric<T>(T test) where T: ITest
{
    Console.WriteLine("Generic : " + test.@var);
}
```

as @Ash Burlaczenko has said you cant name a variable after a keyword, if you reallllly want this prefix with @ symbol to escape the keyword

Comment: This will not work, `ITest` does not have a member named `var`.

Comment: Only going to work if ITest specifies the property var, of course. I'm not sure it does in the example.

Comment: i get a number of errors...
CS0120 : An Object Reference is Required for non-static field/method/property 'DoSomethingClass.PrintGeneric<T>(T)
CS0201 : Only Assignment, call, increment, decrement, new object can be used as a statement
CS0019 : operator < cannote be applied to operands of type Method Group
CS1061 : T does not contain definition myvar

Answer (score 1):

You need to define something in the interface, such as:

```
public interface ITest
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Implement `ITest` in your classes:

```
public class MyClass1 : ITest
{
    public string Name { get { return "Test1"; } }
}

public class MyClass2 : ITest
{
    public string Name { get { return "Test2"; } }
}
```

Then restrict your generic `Print` function, to `ITest`:

```
public void Print<T>(T test) where T : ITest
{
}
```

Comment: See my reply on Ash's comment to the question. You can use `var` as identifier name, just like `yield`, etc., though that's probably not a great idea. It's a contextual keyword. Try `int var;` to verify for yourself.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari, ah..  I was not aware of that.  Well, today I learned.  But yes, it's not something I'd ever actually do :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `var` with the generic.

Try something like

```
Console.WriteLine("Generic : {0}", test);
```

And override `ToString` method [1]

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx