# passing type of property to generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a `generic class` `GenericClass<T>` 
for some reason I need to pass the generic type from another type like that:

say I have some `classes` from `NormalClass1` to `NormalClassN` all of them have property say `prop1` with different `types`
I need to do this

```
var type1 = typeof(NormalClass1).GetProperty("prop1").GetType();
```

and send `type1` to new instance of `GenericClass` like that:

```
 var instance = new GenericClass<type1>();
```

but an error has occurred that says that

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'GenericClass<type1>' to 'GenericClass<T>'
```

how can I pass this type to `GenericClass`

Comment: Have you tried converting it to T first?
If `NormalClass1.prop1` is of type or inhertited from `T` then just convert it to `T` explicitly.
If it is not inherited from `T` then you obviously cannot do this.

Comment: You only know the generic type at runtime so you need the runtime features to create the generic type. You can't use new here that way. Something like `typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(type1)`

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood you. Your question is much more interesting :) Take a look at these:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562685/pass-type-to-generic-method-nested-generic

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666064/c-sharp-get-type-parameter-at-runtime-to-pass-into-a-generic-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.
First of all:

```
var type1 = typeof(NormalClass1).GetProperty("prop1").GetType();
```

will return the type [PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx), not the type of the property. What you want is:

```
var type1 = typeof(NormalClass1).GetProperty("prop1").PropertyType;
```

Second of all you seem to have a conceptual issue with Generics, Types and TypeParameters.

Basically there is a difference between a Type variable (`Type x = typeof(NormalClass1<>`) and a generic Type parameter (the T in `NormalClass<T>`).
T is not much more than a placeholder for a Type. You can use `typeof(T)` to get the actual Type of `T`. Using `typeof(x)` on the other hand would result in a compulation error since x is a variable and not a Type. You would use `x.GetType()` instead.

You cannot create a generic type via a runtime type variable directly.
What you can do instead is creating the generic type via reflection.

The following example should illustrate how to do that

```
var genericTypeParameter = typeof(NormalClass1).GetProperty("prop1").PropertyType;
var genericBaseType = typeof(GenericClass<>);
var genericType = genericBaseType.MakeGenericType(genericTypeParameter);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

As you can see, var instance would substitute to object instance. That has to be that way, since you can check the type of compile time. Best Practice would probably be to create a non generic base class for you generic class. You can than use the base class type and have at least a small amount of type checking at runtime, even if you have no chance to test the generic type parameter.

This would be what it would look like:

```
var instance = (GenericClassBase)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only do it with Reflection:

```
    var generic = typeof (GenericClass<T>).MakeGenericType(type1);
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(generic);
```